# How could we have a non-isothermal deformation without any heat source or heat flux?

Tags: thermodynamics, continuum-mechanics

[image]

I don't understand what does it mean that "no time remains for isothermal removal of heat"? The term "isothermal" means temperature is constant, so how does **isothermal removal of heat** work?

Knowing that a deformation could be split into the mechanical and thermal parts, the given material is not deformed mechanically since its mechanically incompressible, and since they mention "non-isothermal deformation", so how come we have a non-isothermal deformation if there's no heat source or heat flux?

**Source of picture: Nonlinear Solid Mechanics A Continuum Approach for Engineering**

Comment: Are you saying that you can't deform an incompressible material mechanically?  What if you stretch a rubber band?  Isn't that mechanical deformation of an incompressible material?

Comment: Ah okay so I understand thanks. But they go on to say that we have a change of temperature

Comment: If you deform it, you do work on it, and, without heat exchange with the surroundings, its internal energy (and thus temperature) has to change.

Comment: Ahhh, okay! Thank you. By the way, your comment has answered my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To isothermally transfer heat, the transfer must occur in such a way that there exist no thermal gradients anywhere in the system. This means the process must occur so gradually that the temperatures throughout the system equilibrate and stay the same at every infinitesimal time increment. This in turn means an isothermal process will be very *slow*.